# End to end system tests in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, e2e-testing, system-testing, fabric8

I am interested in hearing as to whether there are any frameworks using kubernetes or otherwise that one can use to write end to end system tests with, of a series of modules / applications that talk to each other in a more complex system.

Alternatively I'd be very interested in hearing if it is possible to write system tests using kubernetes from a first principles approach.

My use case is that the modules in question may be written in many different frameworks and languages, but they can all be dockerised individually.

I know that [fabric8](https://github.com/fabric8io/fabric8) claims to [support system testing using kubernetes and arquillian](http://fabric8.io/guide/testing.html), however that seems to have the distinct disadvantage that all the applications need to be written in java, which is very much a no-go for me.

**Update**: It does look like it is possible to write end to end tests in kubernetes for particular examples/use cases, see https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/6183 .  However this issue doesn't seem to have been touched for a while.  Though this does give me some modicum of hope that what I'm after is not impossible.

Ideally, I wouldn't mind being walked through / pointed to work that might help me see an example of e2e tests for a 'hello world' kubernetes example, like k8petstore, or simpler.

In particular, the relevant part of the kubernetes project seems to be https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/test/e2e .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW you can use fabric8-arquillian to test stuff that are not written in java. The only thing that needs to be in java is the test case itself.